# Redirect from pop up window

Tags: asp.net

how can i redirect to other page  from pop up window with response.redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're wanting to do this when the user presses a button or something on the popup. You can use **ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript** function to get ASP.Net to put some JavaScript in the right place so that it's executed as soon as the postback has completed. Something like this...

```
public void RedirectParent(string url)
{
    string js = "";
    js += "window.opener.location.href='" + url + "';";
    js += "window.close();";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType, "redirect", js, true);
}
```

You can remove the **window.close()** line if you want to keep the popup open, but I'm guessing that you want to close it automatically.

The *"redirect"* bit on the last line is just the name that you want to assign to the script - this can be anything you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Once popup is opened to a given URL you cannot use server side script to redirect the parent. You need to use javascript inside the popup:

```
if (opener && !opener.closed) {
    opener.location.href = "http://www.example.com/somenewurl";
}
```